# Displaying Year From SQL Results While Querying m-d-Y

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I grab the m-d-Y from a SQL query like this:

```
    FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") as YEAR_SUBMITTED,
```

But only display the Year (Y) in my PHP/HTML?

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
        echo "\t\t<td><div class=\"boxed\"><center>\n$col_value\n</center></div></td>\n";
    }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Why why why **why *why WHY*** in the name of all things that are Holy would one EVER want to pass dates from MySQL to PHP as a non-standard string?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateTime` class (or even better – [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)):

```
$year = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $col_value)->format('Y');
```

Comment: @navlag I don't really understand your loop. What's the name of your timestamp variable?

Comment: there is no timestamp variable, this loop just displays all the result rows from the queries until there are none left to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td><div class=\"boxed\"><center>\n" .  DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $col_value)->format('Y') . "\n</center></div></td>\n";
}
```